# How to get all location(markers) on google map for a country or state

Tags: c#, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am try to get all the markers (locations) of a particular state using google Map API, but after few requests it return nothing with a message that daily request quota is exceeded

Here the Error message :

```
   "error_message" : "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT"
}
```

I am implementing this in C#, here the code:

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=25.4358011,81.84631100000001&radius=40000&types=stadium&sensor=false&key=MyAPIKey") as HttpWebRequest;
            webRequest.Timeout = 20000;
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            var result = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(RequestCompleted), webRequest);

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)result.AsyncState;
            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(result);
            using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                var r = new StreamReader(stream);
                var resp = r.ReadToEnd();

            }
            Console.ReadLine();
```